How to use yaml with Spring Boot @Value, Could not resolve placeholder 'secret.jwt' in value "${secret.jwt}"
security.yml
Path: src/main/resources/security.yml
## Secret Key

## 1
secret-jwt: my-jwt-secret
## 2
secret.jwt: my-jwt-secret
## 3
secret:
  jwt: my-jwt-secret
  cookey: my-cookey-secret

issuer: https://my-test-project.com

Class which using yml
@PropertySource("classpath:security.yml")
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class TokenProvider(
    @Value("\${secret.jwt}") private val jwtSecretKey: String,

    @Value("\${issuer}") private val issuer: String,
    // ...Several Constuctor Injected Services
) {
    // ...
}

Occured Exception
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'secret.jwt' in value "${secret.jwt}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:921)

Dependencies Summary
Using Kotlin Gradle DSL
jvm version : corretto-21
Kotlin version : 1.9.22
gradle : v8.4
Spring boot starter, web, security : 3.2.1

Working with @Value("\${secret-jwt}") private val jwtSecretKey: String,
Working.
Not working.

So, @PropertySource & @Value works fine. It can load top-level variables well, so @PropertySource Annotation or YAML path is clear. Also it is clear that I used correct @Value annotation, which is from Spring(not Lombok)
Tried Gradle clean/build, Invalidate IntelliJ IDEA Caches several times but nothing changes, so IDEA or Gradle is not the problem.
Does anyone know why nested yaml I wrote(#3) doesn't work? Do I have to create another POJO for configuration? I saw YAML Tutorial, YAML Linter, GPT, Spring Docs, Google but have no clue

you shouldn't escape the dollar sign, just use @Value("${secret.jwt}")

@JAsgarov It's Kotlin code, so if it wasn't escaped there is compile error. And if that was the problem, you can't explain how #1 & #2 still works

@Propertysource doesn't work with YAML files, unless you specify the factory to load it with. By default it will assume .properties files not .yaml files.

@M.Deinum Thanks a lot. Now I see it clear. May I ask you why #1 & #2 worked? I guess #1&#2  don't seem different from .properties, So @PropertySource can read that. Is that right?
